# Low performance when using HDMI display as primary display

Tags: xubuntu

using Ubuntu 16.04 with XFCE I enjoy playing Factorio in spare time. When I run it on the laptop monitor it works great, CPU usage is high and it is turbo boosting. When I connect a display over HDMI and play on it, it works worse and has huge droops in FPS from time to time, CPU usage is around 20% and it is running at a mere 0.80GHz

Note: For those thinking that the cable is the problem: the cable works fine in Windows and while doing anything else. It is a gold plated HDMI 2.0 cable. I have it connected with an adapter from mini Display Port 2 to HDMI 2.0

Comment: Do you have different resolutions on the monitors? Did you try to switch off the laptop monitor when using the HDMI connected one?

Comment: Laptop resolution 1366*768

Comment: Monitor resolution 1920*1080, I use xrandr to switch off laptop display and switch on monitor display

Comment: I would definitely try switching off the laptop display, and maybe try to set the HDMI to a lower resolution (e.g 1280x720). What graphics card do you have, and, if AMD or Nvidia, are you using the proprietary drivers ?

Comment: Alright, then try to lower the resolution as JonasCz already mentioned and compare the performance. If it is OK @1366*768 on the HDMI monitor, your graphics card is the limiting factor.

Comment: The change in resolution does not change anything, I am using Intel graphics with the proprietary driver from their website. My issue is that when I connect the monitor and start the game, my CPU undercooks itself for no reason.